# Perl- How Do i know when socket client is disconnected (when user closes window/browser)

Tags: html, perl, sockets, websocket

I am using HTML 5 and Perl web server socket. Can the socket server know when user closes the browser? please help 
Server:

```
  Net::WebSocket::Server->new(
    listen => 8080,
    on_connect => sub {
        my ($serv, $conn) = @_;
        $conn->on(
            utf8 => sub {
                my ($conn, $msg) = @_;
                $conn->send_utf8($msg);
            },
        disconnect => sub {
        my ($conn, $code, $reason) = @_;
        $conn->disconnect();
    },
        );
    },
)->start;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Set up a handler for [the `disconnect` event](http://search.cpan.org/~topaz/Net-WebSocket-Server/lib/Net/WebSocket/Server/Connection.pm#EVENTS) on the socket:

```
$conn->on(
    disconnect => sub {
        my ($conn, $code, $reason) = @_;
        ...
    },
 );
```

Comment: I tried this but it did not work. can you please share the code if you have. Thanks in advance

Comment: If you're trying something that isn't working, *post what isn't working*. We can't debug blindly.

Comment: I am trying to close the connection when client disconnects/closes the window. I have updated the code in question. I an learning perl and web sockets. Please help. Is the code that I have written correct?

Comment: The connection is already disconnecting when your handler receives the `disconnect` event. You don't need to disconnect it a second time.

Comment: But when I close the browser, the server socket is still executing. It is not closing the socket connection........when I close the browser/tab I want the socket script to end

Comment: Browsers do close WebSockets when tabs or windows close — I verified this by adding a `print` into the `disconnect` handler of your code above. Or do you want the *whole* server to shut down after a client disconnects?

Comment: Yes, I need my server to shutdown. How Can i do this?

Comment: You could `exit`, I guess? But don't do that. That's a really bad idea.

Comment: Can you please share me the code that you executed (print statement when client is closed).

Comment: Did you print any statement when client closed the window?